# Using the human interface driver on ubuntu

Tags: linux, beagleboard

I am using the [tmp006evm](http://www.ti.com/tool/tmp006evm) on my beagle board running ubuntu 12.04. According to the question I posted here http://e2e.ti.com/support/other_analog/temperature_sensors/f/243/p/199962/712785.aspx#712785 , they do not provide official support for the linux machines.What would be the simplest way by which I can get the tmp006evm working on my beagle board? I am thinking it is libusb. Could someone correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know that it's a HID-device and by the fact that it is using a National Instruments raw USB driver, you can easily use libusb to access it, in case you have a protocol documentation for that board. Might be using USB interrupts so it might be quite easy even without protocol specifications. Have a look at [this](http://lascar-usb-termometer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/usb_termometer.c). I used it for an EL-USB-RT some time ago. However, I do not know any out-of-the-box GUIs for libusb and HID-devices.

Comment: Do I have to use SnoopyPro or something like that to decode the protocol beacause I cannot seem to find the protocol documentation anywhere